# Failed to start service 'Microsoft Service Fabric Host Service (FabricHostSvc)'

Tags: azure-service-fabric

Failed to start service 'Microsoft Service Fabric Host Service (FabricHostSvc)'.

1 >> Start-Service : Failed to start service 'Microsoft Service Fabric Host Service (FabricHostSvc)'.
At C:\Program Files\Microsoft SDKs\Service Fabric\Tools\Scripts\ClusterSetupUtilities.psm1:433 char:5
+ Start-Service FabricHostSvc -WarningAction SilentlyContinue
+ ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
+ CategoryInfo : OpenError: (System.ServiceProcess.ServiceController:ServiceController) [Start-Service], ServiceCommandException
+ FullyQualifiedErrorId : StartServiceFailed,Microsoft.PowerShell.Commands.StartServiceCommand

StartLocalCluster : Could not start FabricHostSvc
At C:\Program Files\Microsoft SDKs\Service Fabric\ClusterSetup\DevClusterSetup.ps1:70 char:1
+ StartLocalCluster
+ ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
+ CategoryInfo : NotSpecified: (:) [Write-Error], WriteErrorException
+ FullyQualifiedErrorId : Microsoft.PowerShell.Commands.WriteErrorException,StartLocalCluster

ScriptHalted
ScriptHalted
At C:\Program Files\Microsoft SDKs\Service Fabric\Tools\Scripts\ClusterSetupUtilities.psm1:437 char:9
+ throw
+ ~~~~~
+ CategoryInfo : OperationStopped: (:) [], RuntimeException
+ FullyQualifiedErrorId : ScriptHalted

2 >> FabricHostSvc is always in 'Starting' State even though I tried manually restart.

3 >> Event Log Details:
Faulting application name: FabricHost.exe, version: 5.1.150.9590, time stamp: 0x5751636d
Faulting module name: FabricHost.exe, version: 5.1.150.9590, time stamp: 0x5751636d
Exception code: 0xc0000602
Fault offset: 0x00000000000b844e
Faulting process id: 0x2e30
Faulting application start time: 0x01d1d1fed21076d3
Faulting application path: C:\Program Files\Microsoft Service Fabric\bin\FabricHost.exe
Faulting module path: C:\Program Files\Microsoft Service Fabric\bin\FabricHost.exe

4>> There is no ScheduledJob FabricCounters to remove. (Tried that also)

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem. Run Visual Studio as Administrator.